# Gmail imap can't access folders with space (or other escapted characters) in the title

Tags: shell, ubuntu, gmail, imap

Lets say i'm connection to imap.gmail.com via shell

```
>> openssl s_client -connect imap.gmail.com:993 -crlf
>> a1 login asdasd@gmail.com asdasdasdasd
```

Getting the list of the folders:

```
>> a1 list "" *
```

Respond:

```
....
* LIST (\HasChildren) "/" "github"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Wizz&AKA-Air"
....
```

Now lets try to select the mailbox:

**This will work**:

```
a1 select "github"
```

*Respond*:

```
* FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $NotJunk $NotPhishing $Phishing)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $NotJunk $NotPhishing $Phishing \*)] Flags permitted.
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 639992816] UIDs valid.
* 4 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* OK [UIDNEXT 5] Predicted next UID.
* OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 4768827]
a1 OK [READ-WRITE] github selected. (Success)
```

**This will return error**:

```
a1 select "Wizz&AKA-Air"
```

*Respond*:

```
a1 select "Wizz&AKA-Air"
a1 NO [NONEXISTENT] Unknown Mailbox: Wizz&AKA-Air (now in authenticated state) (Failure)
```

So, "&AKA-" is just escape for the white space, but I can't select the mailbox with the white space. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't use utf-7 just for a space.  Using double quotes is sufficient.

Comment: @Max, `a1 select "Wizz Air"` doesn't work as well. Respond: `a1 NO [NONEXISTENT] Unknown Mailbox: Wizz Air (Failure)`

Comment: Sounds like Gmail has a bug/desync in their IMAP implementation.  I would rename the tag and then rename it back.

Comment: @Max, nice call! That actually helped! Now the folder is `* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" "Wizz Air"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folder "Wizz Air" was originally imported form mailbox on Yandex.com and that was the issue. The issue was solved after I renamed the tag and then renamed it back